# Generate all square sub-matrices of a given size

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

You will be given a square matrix of integers **M** and another positive integer **n**, strictly smaller than the size of **M**. Your task is to generate all square sub-matrices of **M** of size **n**.

For the purposes of this challenge, a *square sub-matrix* is a group of **adjacent** rows and columns contained in **M**.

### Input / Output Formats

You are free to choose any other reasonable formats, these are just some examples.

**Input**

- A matrix in the native matrix type (if your language has one)
- A 2D array (an array of 1D arrays, each corresponding to one row / one column)
- A 1D array (since the matrix is always square)
- A string (you chose the spacing, but please do not abuse this in any way), etc.

**Output**

- A matrix of matrices.
- A 4D array, where each element (3D list) represents the sub-matrices on a row/column.
- A 3D array, where each element (2D list) represents a sub-matrix.
- A string representation of the resulting sub-matrices, etc.

### Specs

- You may choose to take the *size* of **M** as input too. It is guaranteed to be at least **2**.
- The orientation of the output is arbitrary: you may choose to output the sub-matrices as lists of columns or lists of rows, but your choice must be consistent.
- You can compete in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/59487) and can take input and provide output through any [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), while taking note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) for *every language* wins.

### Example

Given **n = 3** and **M**:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

The possible **3x3** submatrices are:

```
+-------+        +--------+     1  2  3  4         1  2  3  4
|1  2  3| 4     1| 2  3 4 |     +--------+         +--------+
|5  6  7| 8     5| 6  7 8 |     |5   6  7|8       5| 6  7  8|
|9 10 11|12     9|10 11 12|     |9  10 11|12      9|10 11 12|
+-------+        +--------+     |13 14 15|16     13|14 15 16|
13 14 15 16     13 14 15 16     +--------+         +--------+
```

So the result would be:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11]], [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12]], [[5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14, 15]], [[6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16]]]
```

As noted above, an output of:

```
[[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11]], [[2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]], [[5, 9, 13], [6, 10, 14], [7, 11, 15]], [[6, 10, 14], [7, 11, 15], [8, 12, 16]]]
```

would also be acceptable, if you choose to return the sub-matrices as lists of rows instead.

### Test cases

The inputs **M, n**:

```
[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11]], 1
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], 3
[[100,-3,4,6],[12,11,14,8],[0,0,9,3],[34,289,-18,3]], 2
[[100,-3,4,6],[12,11,14,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], 3
```

And the corresponding outputs (sub-matrices given as lists of rows):

```
[[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[5]],[[6]],[[7]],[[9]],[[10]],[[11]]]
[[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11]],[[2,3,4],[6,7,8],[10,11,12]],[[5,6,7],[9,10,11],[13,14,15]],[[6,7,8],[10,11,12],[14,15,16]]]
[[[100,-3],[12,11]],[[-3,4],[11,14]],[[4,6],[14,8]],[[12,11],[0,0]],[[11,14],[0,9]],[[14,8],[9,3]],[[0,0],[34,289]],[[0,9],[289,-18]],[[9,3],[-18,3]]]
[[[100,-3,4],[12,11,14],[9,10,11]],[[-3,4,6],[11,14,8],[10,11,12]],[[12,11,14],[9,10,11],[13,14,15]],[[11,14,8],[10,11,12],[14,15,16]]]
```

Or, as lists of columns:

```
[[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[5]],[[6]],[[7]],[[9]],[[10]],[[11]]]
[[[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7,11]],[[2,6,10],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]],[[5,9,13],[6,10,14],[7,11,15]],[[6,10,14],[7,11,15],[8,12,16]]]
[[[100,12],[-3,11]],[[-3,11],[4,14]],[[4,14],[6,8]],[[12,0],[11,0]],[[11,0],[14,9]],[[14,9],[8,3]],[[0,34],[0,289]],[[0,289],[9,-18]],[[9,-18],[3,3]]]
[[[100,12,9],[-3,11,10],[4,14,11]],[[-3,11,10],[4,14,11],[6,8,12]],[[12,9,13],[11,10,14],[14,11,15]],[[11,10,14],[14,11,15],[8,12,16]]]]
```

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14794/59487) (now deleted, only users with over 2k reputation can view it). Thanks to everyone who has given feedback.

Comment: So is [this output format](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwEEXBq7xSwcKfTaKSo4QUEiwExUa8/jrz9Hf/DvfzDv25hioCRiwkMgtrYUMzEgoFGYooodwmqmFtxP0H) allowed?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, it is allowed.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
2FεŒsù}ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7CcMwFEbh3rOcC/6vJD8WyBJChQ2ZIHWWyC4GpzZps5IslQe@M6Zt17NWf/yP3@d1fd/XWWvOwpxAJBXyhM0s2IrGlhJyTAFF1IFpQjNa0NrGjly446FlxFMpQ7gB)

**Explanation**

```
2F            # 2 times do:
  ε    }      # apply to each element in the input matrix (initially rows)
   Œsù        # get a list of sublists of size input_2
        ø     # transpose (handling columns on the second pass of the loop)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
thYC
```

Inputs are `n`,  then `M`.

The output is a matrix, where each column contains all the columns of a submatrix.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDYAwDEXBnineCPw4DiCXTIGiFHQU0GV/c/fd882cz3Vm2tJFwaiB09jYgwOtSKgEMlSRozZ@)

#### Explanation

```
thY    % Address the compiler with a formal, slightly old-fashioned determiner
C      % Convert input to ouput
```

More seriously, `t` takes input **n** implictly and duplicates it on the stack. `h` concatenates both copies of **n**, producing the array **[n, n]**. `YC` takes input **M** implicitly, extracts all its **[n, n]**-size blocks, and arranges them as columns in column-major order. This means that the columns of each block are stacked vertically to form a single column.

Comment: LOL +1 for "formal, slightly old-fashioned pronoun", and a very nice golf.

Comment: @Giuseppe I just realised it’s a determiner, not a pronoun :-/

Comment: Well, I always learned "thy/your" as possessive pronouns; this is my first time hearing of a determiner!

Comment: @Giuseppe "Thy/your" are possessive determiners, that is, they go with a name: "This is your car". "Thine/yours" are possessive pronouns, that is, the name is omitted: "This is yours". And I initially confused "thy" with a personal pronoun, which would actually be "thou". What a mess I've made :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous infix lambda taking **n** as left argument and **M** as right argument.

```apl
{s↓(-s←2⍴⌈¯1+⍺÷2)↓⊢⌺⍺ ⍺⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Tq4kdtkzV0geQEo0e9Wx71dBxab6j9qHfX4e1GmkCpR12LHvXsAvIVgBjE6d1a@98zr6C0BKjjUdvER31TvYL9/bj8S0ugYhCBRx0zQLqBCMz4D5FXMFRIUwDrVlCPjjbUMdIxjtWJNtEx1TED0uY6FjqWsbHqUMMUjDEU65gAlQEV6wCVAlmWOoYGOoaGOoZGQI6hsY6hiY6hqY6hGZIZRihmGBjo6AINAdtmaATWagI2yUDHQMcS7BhjEx0jC0sdXUMLIBeXW3Cag8dFAA)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda where `⍺` is the left argument and `⍵` is the right argument:

`⊢⍵` yield the right argument (`⊢` separates `⍺ ⍺` from `⍵`)

`⊢⌺⍺ ⍺` all `⍺`-by-`⍺` submatrices including those overlapping the edges (those are padded with zeros)

`(`…`)↓` drop the following number elements along the first two dimensions:

`⍺÷2` half of `⍺`

`¯1+` negative one plus that

`⌈` round up

`2⍴` cyclically **r**eshape to a list of two elements

`s←` store in `s` (for **s**hards)

`-` negate (i.e. drop from the rear)

`s↓` drop `s` elements along the first and second dimensions (from the front)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{(1↓2 1 3 4⍉⊖)⍣(4×⌊⍺÷2)⊢⌺⍺ ⍺⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY07CsJAFEX7rOKWM4Xgm3zUJVgIFoJ1jIkENBEmKURsA4YMKIJWNroGEdJmJ28jMdmCxYV7mnP8/XawPvjbdNO2R0Fc3BQINhw2Zy7vks1bOM2Dq5JN3XyV5PLFVd0BuvVgPqe2ZfPEzI8TRHkSZHGaQOh8tYu17r60rAhcXPB3wLL6wCLUGQJfhxpiOZ13Wjvi4ioIqhdK4cLDCGMpJqAhiEBKCrJBDsgFefIH)

A different approach than Adám's.

Comment: Do you intend to provide an explanation (after you've finished golfing of course)? I'd be interested to see how it works (and I don't know APL at all) :)

Comment: @Emigna Yeah, if I have time by then.

Comment: Very clever. If you can successfully use dyadic `⍉` for non-trivial cases, then you have truly mastered array programming.

Comment: @Adám Uh, although I think this answer is in fact invalid :-( EDIT: Fixed, but now it's 31 bytes long...

Comment: Feel free to copy the test suite from my submission.

Comment: @Adám I would, but that's not how I do test suites at all. I'm still golfing this answer BTW. DUH `(∪2,⍳4)` is the same length as `2 1 3 4` >_> OK looks like there's nothing left to golf.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(M,N,S,W=1:N,g=N:S-N)for(i in g)for(j in g)print(M[i+W,j+W,drop=F])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoJAGITvPYXHlUbwdzfTJa/d9GLgITqUsbJCqyxG9fTbWlDIMDAw3zDWqWAXBU7dTTvpwbASFWo0BckKXVHJOqpCNVimA22C7hP7bxytNhMrj3rdoPe@2mEs9qfQKXY7T1Y/GUlKIbwuLzs8ikMIDhGufn3rCY6N3CKXRHPL/yiBL9E4RuT3SEEJiEACGWKvfB4KJFmOiDI/W34m/tO9AQ)

Takes `M`, `N`, and the `S`ize of the matrix.

Prints the resultant matrices to stdout; `drop=F` is needed so the in the `N=1` case the indexing doesn't drop the `dim` attribute and yields a `matrix` rather than a `vector`.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoJAGITvPYXHlUbwd810yWs3vRh4iA5lrK2QG5thPf22FhQyDAzMN4yx0tsEnpWPvhmU7lmBEhXqnESJNi9FFZS@1IYpT/Ve@4ndN94vemTFXi1rdM5no2/59uBbya7HwagnI0EJYqfTy@gx3/ngiP3Fr28cwbESa2SCaGr5HyXwORqGCNweCSgCEShGitApm4YxojRDQKmbzT8j92nf "R – Try It Online") with `print` -> `show`

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>11</strike> 8 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to miles

```
<;._3~,~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY4xDsIwEAT7vGKEIpmIxPL5THACVEhUVHwgBSICGn6QrxtHER0FJ213szuvtLJm5NhjqHH0OY3ldL2c02FvB53qKVUFxf32eMNa0VLwKFtadnSIQ6RiRJYf0/w8820IhFI2TyvtDOk/0MI4x6CEPCs@TyKBmG1ddshWAR87Bono3OvTBw)

Comment: This uses 8 bytes `<;._3~,~` and uses a hook instead to pair the size with itself, then cuts and boxes each since a matrix of matrices is allowed as output.

Comment: @miles Thanks, it's elegant now!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 67 bytes

```hs
m#n|r<-[0..length m-n]=[take n.drop x<$>take n(drop y m)|x<-r,y<-r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcdLCsIwFEbhrfzQDhRugtZHFVI3Eu4gYLClybXEDFro3uNrcjhf716jD6GUWMmajLI7rYOXR@4RlXBnsxs9RN/Tc8Js6tvfm58XxO06G5Vo@YRLdIOgw5QGyahh7Z7QEA5MsEfCiXD@bku4EK7MqNCUNw)

Comment: Oops! I was too late :)  [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##nVFNb4JAEL3zKwbsQZPBsIAoifTQq0099Lgh0URaQD6MYoLG/06XYUElNE3K4S2zO2/em5lwe9oHSVJVkRp7xXYfQDTdHfMDxEo6Km/Xpc6N6TQJsu8ihFQvfY@Xarx8eR2XajRJb9FSv2IswK9K2JzC/Jzs3oINXMCDw7n4LI7vGYyjLyg97wJFGGSgrVcaBMkpAO0jL2C9UrWJoqTbKBOcXa6A@DhnaKLlI5@hg3NxusgMZMz3YQTsQYnSawIXb8i5SWgRzggdwjmhS8iM5hAM/1EO7VYQF3dJZKYImIXMRjZD5pAHa9jDb65rZ1KgLd8VJ6s9wl2w6aHPEb@dm64Hw0BdaKBTP5uUaRPNQANdMmbZaC5c1NlChHUf5nAfVKotQxb0xj0VpQupUyvQNM3Gt9CS060T61gO3ZZDbXZTp7V25IUrDmmuWRY5llb/bvI/65LFHkr1lnaX6nSe9jZA661ugPi8PKX6AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Z⁹Ƥ⁺€
```

Uses the 4D output format. For 3D, append a `Ẏ` for **6 bytes**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/qUePOY0seNe561LTm////0dEKhjoKCkZAbAzEJrE6XArRCqZAphkQmwOxBUTIUkfB0ACIgaoNjcBChkANhiZADFRtaBYb@98YAA)

#### How it works

```
Z⁹Ƥ⁺€  Main link. Left argument: M (matrix). Right argument: n (integer)

 ⁹Ƥ    Apply the link to the left to all infixes of length n.
Z        Zip the rows of the infix, transposing rows and columns.
   ⁺€  Map Z⁹Ƥ over all results.
```

Comment: I suggested something similar to user202729 in chat. An alternative 5-byter is `ṡ€Zṡ€`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
{tN&s₎\;Ns₎}ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7rET634UVNfjLUfiKp9uG3B///R0dGGBgY68cY6JjpmsTrRhkY6hoY6hiY6FkCOgY6BjqWOMZBlbKJjZGGpE29oAeTG6hjF/o8CAA)

This returns lists of columns.

Technically, `tN&s₎\;Ns₎` is a generating predicate which unifies its output with any of those submatrices. We use `{…}ᶠ` only to expose all possibilities.

#### Explanation

```
 tN&              Call the second argument of the input N
{          }ᶠ     Find all:
    s₎              A substring of the matrix of size N
      \             Transpose that substring
       ;Ns₎         A substring of that transposed substring of size N
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```apl
t∘↑¨(¯1-t←-2⍴⎕)↓,⍀⍪\⍪¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/6XPOqY8aht4qEVGofWG@qWACV0jR71bgGq0nzUNlnnUW/Do95VMUB8aAVQ7D9Qz/80LqAGDUMDA4VD640VTBTMNDUMjRQMDRUMTRQsNDUsFQwNwDwjoLgxSNDQVMHQTJPLGAA)

the result is a matrix of matrices, though Dyalog's output formatting doesn't make that very obvious

input the matrix (`⎕`), turn each element into a nested matrix of its own (`⍪¨`), take prefix concatenations by row (`,\`) and by column (`⍪⍀`), input n (`⎕`), drop the first n-1 rows and columns of nested matrices (`(¯1-t←-2⍴⎕)↓`), take the bottom right n-by-n corner from each matrix (`t∘↑¨`)

```apl
                                        ┌─┬──┬───┐
                                        │a│ab│abc│      ┼──┼───┤        ┼──┼───┤
 n=2       ┌─┬─┬─┐      ┌─┬──┬───┐      ├─┼──┼───┤      │ab│abc│        │ab│ bc│
┌───┐      │a│b│c│      │a│ab│bac│      │a│ab│abc│      │de│def│        │de│ ef│
│abc│  ⍪¨  ├─┼─┼─┤  ,\  ├─┼──┼───┤  ⍪⍀  │d│de│def│ 1 1↓ ┼──┼───┤¯2 ¯2∘↑¨┼──┼───┤
│def│ ---> │d│e│f│ ---> │d│de│edf│ ---> ├─┼──┼───┤ ---> │ab│abc│  --->  │  │   │
│ghi│      ├─┼─┼─┤      ├─┼──┼───┤      │a│ab│abc│      │de│def│        │de│ ef│
└───┘      │g│h│i│      │g│gh│hgi│      │d│de│def│      │gh│ghi│        │gh│ hi│
           └─┴─┴─┘      └─┴──┴───┘      │g│gh│ghi│      ┴──┴───┘        ┴──┴───┘
                                        └─┴──┴───┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
│Æ☼♂Mqß E╖
```

[Run it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=%E2%94%82%C3%86%E2%98%BC%E2%99%82Mq%C3%9F+E%E2%95%96&i=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%2C%5B9%2C10%2C11%2C12%5D%2C%5B13%2C14%2C15%2C16%5D%5D%2C+3&a=1)

The ascii representation of the same program is

```
YBFMyBF|PMmJ
```

It works like this.

```
Y               Store the number in the y register
 B              Batch the grid into y rows each
  F             Foreach batch, run the rest of the program
   M            Transpose about the diagonal
    yB          Batch the transposed slices into y rows each
      F         Foreach batch, run the rest of the progoram
       |P       Print a blank line
         M      Transpose inner slice - restoring its original orientation
          mJ    For each row in the inner grid, output joined by spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(a)(n)`. Returns the results as lists of rows.

```js
a=>n=>(g=x=>a[y+n-1]?[a.slice(y,y+n).map(r=>r.slice(x,x+n)),...g(a[x+n]?x+1:!++y)]:[])(y=0)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>n=>(g=x=>a[y+n-1]?[a.slice(y,y+n).map(r=>r.slice(x,x+n)),...g(a[x+n]?x+1:!++y)]:[])(y=0)

;[
  [ [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11]], 1 ],
  [ [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], 3 ],
  [ [[100,-3,4,6],[12,11,14,8],[0,0,9,3],[34,289,-18,3]], 2 ],
  [ [[100,-3,4,6],[12,11,14,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], 3]
]
.forEach(([m, a]) => console.log(JSON.stringify(f(m)(a))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
TmoTmX¹X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDoAgEEXBC73CzwLqPShICL2JIRbGw9l6sZVu5nju072Mq4z6vdXdzVsTASN2WiKzsk3taEFCYUaGIkoo9/4D) This function takes **n** and **M** and returns a matrix of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->c,g{n=c.size-g+1
(0...n*n).map{|i|c[i/n,g].map{|z|z[i%n,g]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu9DsIgFIbhnatgMfHngJy2NjrgjRAGJZYwcNJoHKRw7Vh0fN4v3/N9/9RJV3F14BfSTr5Cegh/QLZVUkra007G27zkkJ0JRwJv/045mbBpLqXUyDU3BpUC0cMAowWDHSACDnBecQFUP3Zt6VvGE@BoLaP12rOZTyYC2foF)

This is a lambda taking a 2D array and an int, returning a 3D array.

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->m,n{
  a = m.size - n + 1     # The count of rows in m that can be a first row in a submatrix
  (0...a*a).map{ |b|     # There will be a*a submatrices
    m[b/a,n].map{ |r|    # Take each possible set of n rows
      r[b%a,n]           # And each possible set of n columns
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:(lambda R:[[r[i:i+n]for r in a[j:j+n]]for i in R for j in R])(range(len(a)+1-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9BbsMgEEXX7SlmF1C@JQY7jk2UHiJbyoKqcYuVkAhlk9O7gBJ1167483mPEdf77fsS9TLt35eTP398evKIRjzywVibbDBhHd10SZQoRPJ2NnMuahNKc6AS5xqdFMnHr6M4HaPwcs1NlHIp9/nhQlhhLUOjdbAb9NjmcwQrMDsHYgl6EuieDIZfCqzzwC24A2/AfdHah6YUmuyhL4iudFdlBYWxLm076GFEw0Mes6r/U//eS868vlxTiLfyQ6z2bytMIke5o1ovPw)

Comment: `def f(a,n):R=range(len(a)+1-n);print[[r[i:i+n]for r in a[j:j+n]]for i in R for j in R]` saves five.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
◫⊟.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4per4oqfLgoKZiAxIFtbMSAyIDNdIFs1IDYgN10gWzkgMTAgMTFdXQpmIDMgW1sxIDIgMyA0XSBbNSA2IDcgOF0gWzkgMTAgMTEgMTJdIFsxMyAxNCAxNSAxNl1dCmYgMiBbWzEwMCDCrzMgNCA2XSBbMTIgMTEgMTQgOF0gWzAgMCA5IDNdIFszNCAyODkgwq8xOCAzXV0KZiAzIFtbMTAwIMKvMyA0IDZdIFsxMiAxMSAxNCA4XSBbOSAxMCAxMSAxMl0gWzEzIDE0IDE1IDE2XV0K)

```
◫⊟.
  .  # duplicate
 ⊟   # couple
◫    # windows
```